Typescript and autogenerated .ts files in separate folder
I have a program: /home/me/project/main.ts
import {Sobaka} from "./auto/sobaka.js"
import {Blabla} from "./auto/blabla.js"
console.log("hello")

Also i have the /home/me/project/tsconfig.json like this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target" : "ES2016",
    "module" : "nodenext",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": false,
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strictNullChecks" : true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization" : true,
    "outDir" : "/tmp/some/output/dir/blabla",
    "rootDirs" : [
       "/tmp/generated",
       "/home/me/project"
    ]
  },
  "include" : [
    "/home/me/project/main.ts"
   ]
}

So, I run: tsc --build /home/me/project/tsconfig.json.
Also I have autogenerated .ts files in the folder /tmp/generated/:
/tmp/generated/auto/sobaka.js
/tmp/generated/auto/blablabla.js

These files generated by some another tool, and I dont want keep them in my source tree.
So, adding /tmp/generated/ to rootDirs i expect ./auto/sobaka.js will be found as /tmp/generated/auto/sobaka.js but I get this:
/home/me/project/main.ts:N:M - error TS2307: Cannot find module './auto/sobaka.js' or its corresponding type declarations.

So, how to deal with .ts files scattered in different places in filesystem and import modules from them?
Tried this: replaced my import with this
import {Sobaka} from @auto/sobaka.js

and added this to tsconfig.json:
...
"baseUrl" : "/home/me/project/",
"paths" : {
   "@auto/*" : ["/tmp/generated/auto/*"]
}
...

Did not helped.

I'm confused. You should not import the compiled build artifact of a codebase, into a source file in that same codebase. You should import the typescript file, and the compiler will simply compile everything at once. What you trying to accomplish? This feels like an XY problem https://xyproblem.info/

@AlexWayne i want include {Sobaka} class from the file /tmp/generated/auto/sobaka.ts
